# can't install curl on mac 10.7.5

Tags: macos, curl, installation

In the terminal when I run the following command

```
brew install curl
```

the error I get is:

```
Updating Homebrew...
==> Downloading https://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.58.0.tar.bz2
curl: (35) error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert  protocol version
Trying a mirror...
```

I downloaded curl-7.58.0.tar.bz2 and put it in library/cache/homebrew as suggested at

[https://github.com/mistydemeo/tigerbrew/issues/506]

This was supposed to recognise that the file was downloaded but didn't.
Yet if I type in the terminal

```
curl --version
```

the message I get is:

```
curl 7.21.4 (universal-apple-darwin11.0) libcurl/7.21.4 OpenSSL/0.9.8z   zlib/1.2.5
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp
```

Does the message above mean that curl is installed correctly for use? I hope this makes sense.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Try `curl www.google.com`. You should get a response like:

```
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&amp;dcr=0&amp;ei=-A2MWpicIumBtge67a34Bw">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

which is Google redirecting you.

Comment: yes I do get this response. Could you please give me more detail on what this means. Thanks

Comment: curl makes http requests, just as your web browser does. Your browser understands what to do with that response,but your terminal doesn't, so it displays it as plain text. Try `curl http://www.columbia.edu/~fdc/sample.html`. Also, go to [that page](http://www.columbia.edu/~fdc/sample.html) in your browser, right click anywhere on the page, and click 'View page source'. You'll see the same response. Helpfully, that page explains what all the html means.

Comment: what will I need to do to download to download curl-7.58.0.tar.bz2 and install it.

Comment: Why do you need to do that if you already have a working install of curl?

Comment: I was following a tutorial at: https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/#xcode on How to install Xcode, Homebrew, Git, RVM, Ruby & Rails on Mac OS X  and was just following the steps outlined.

Comment: so I think my confusion is with the terminal messages thanks

Comment: I have then tried to install the heroku toolbelt and it automatically tries to install curl and git so I get the same errors as at the top of the post